# Proper Way in using Xdebug and Netbeans for Remote Debugging PHP website on a localhost machine

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I'm having trouble with remote debugging using xdebug and netbeans configuration.

I can debug using xdebug and netbeans on localhost and it is working great.. but on a remote server, What happen was when I put a breakpoint and debug the file, it just dont stop on any breakpoints. i don't know what I am missing since im new to this.. here is my basic setup so far.

on my php ini file

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```

and on my netbeans, i have configured the remote connection and works great with the connection here is the settings on run configuration

```
Run As = Remote Web Site (FTP, SFTP)
Project Url =  http://www.somewebsite.com/
Index File = index.php
Arguments = none since it has n arguments at first

inside Remote Connection :  
host Name = host IP(eg 69.123.123.123)
encryption = Pure Ftp
username = someuser
password = somepassword
initial directory = /
timeout = 30
keep alive interval = 30
Passive mode = checked

Upload directory = blank
Upload Files = manually
```

Hope somebody can help me point out what I am missing and what to do, i hardly understand some technical configurations on this, If you can help me through step by step, I know i can follow. looking forward to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a path mapping, otherwise netbeans sets breakpoints on the wrong paths. If you make a remote log file (http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log) you'll see what paths it's setting breakpoints on. See https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/path_mapping_in_php_debugger for info about path mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the remote host to the name or IP of the machine running Netbeans, instead of localhost.

xdebug.remote_host=localhost

change to e.g.:

xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.10

The reason is, that Xdebug on your server will try to connect to your Netbeans-Machine for debugging - not the other way around - so your server needs to know the address of the "remote" machine.

Oh, and also make sure that your local windows-firewall will allow connections from your server on port 9000.